# Edit value in javascript string

Tags: reactjs, replace, react-router, chat

Take a look in my code :

```
<div id="body"></div>

<script>
          var myName = "Leon";

          var message = "Are You Okey @Leon ?";

          if(message.search(myName) !== -1){
             var body = document.getElementById('body');
             body.innerHTML = message;
          }

</script>
```

If my name is in the message, then the result was appear on body. now i want to make a link for my name.
how can change message to following result:

```
Are You Okey <a href="/link">@Leon</a> ?
```

I want to use **react-router**.

Also my react code is :

```
const { uid, name, text, time, friend } = this.props;

        let myName = '@' + getItem('name'); // result is, eg: @Leon

        let thisMessage = text;

        if(thisMessage.includes(myName)){
            thisMessage = thisMessage.replace('@' + myName, `<a href="/link">@${myName}</a>`);
        }

        var message =
            <div className="chat-msg">
                <li>
                    {time}
                </li>
                <li>
                    {name}
                </li>
                <p>
                     {thisMessage}
                </p>
            </div>;

        return message;
```

i need to use for example this code in replace:

```
<Router>
      <Link to={ '/user/' + uid} className="grey">
        {myName}
      </Link>
</Router>
```

But result was like this `[Object Object]`

**UPDATE:
I solved it by edit following part:**

```
    if(thisMessage.includes(myName)){

        var myLink =
            <Router>
                <Link to={ '/user/' + uid} className="grey">
                    {myName}
                </Link>
            </Router>;

        thisMessage = thisMessage.split(myName);
        for (var i = 1; i < thisMessage.length; i += 2) {
            thisMessage[i] = myLink 
        }
    }
```

Now everything is worked fine. thanks friends.

Comment: You can just set the HTML with `innerHTML`: `body.innerHTML = 'Are You Okey <a href="/link">@Leon</a> ?';`

Comment: This way not worked in my case.

Comment: I don't see any react code here, but if you are using it see https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. First, check if the message includes the name. If found then replace the name with a link.

```js
var myName = "Leon";
var message = "Are You Okey @Leon ?";

if (message.includes(myName)) {
    message = message.replace('@' + myName, `<a href="/link">@${myName}</a>`);
    document.querySelector('#body').innerHTML = message;
}
```

```html
<div id="body"></div>
```

Comment: What does it say? any error? Share your react environment.

Comment: As you declare this like ```let myName = '@' + getItem('name');``` so remove the @ sign from this line ```thisMessage = thisMessage.replace('@' + myName, `x`);```

Comment: i tested, but result was like this : <a href="/link">@leon</a>, not html

Comment: Is ```getItem('name')``` returns you the correct value?

Comment: Yes `getItem('name')` is true and your code is fine. but i need to replace react router for link.